# centre overlay spinner on any element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a spinner class that when assigned to any element, it should show an spinner overlay and centred.

I created this jfiddle of my current progress, but I am stuck, I can't seem to centre the spinner on the parent div.

See here: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/L1opn7ks/)

HTML:

```
<div class="u-loading">
<div class="address-container u-border-all">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--line u-border-bottom">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--house-no u-border-right">
    <input type="text" class="address__textbox address__textbox--street">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--line">
    <input type="text" class="address__textbox address__textbox--line">
    <input type="text" class="address__textbox address__textbox--line">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--postcode u-border-right u-border-top">
    <select class="address__textbox address__country u-border-top">
        <option value="Select a country" selected="selected" class="rps-placeholder">Select a country</option>
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
        <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    ##Loading
\*------------------------------------*/


/* Absolute Center CSS Spinner */
.u-loading {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}


.u-loading:not(:required):after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    content: '';
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.u-border-all {
    border: solid black 2px;
}

.address-container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I tried position absolute but that affects the main div. I want to be able to assign this class to most elements and see a spinner.

Any suggestion?

Comment: spinner aligned should be centered verically and horizontally?

Comment: then you can set 

 position: absolute;
top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
on this selector .u-loading:not(:required)::after

Comment: This centres the spinner relative to the whole page instead of the div it was assigned to

Comment: Please see answer below. Set position relative on desired div where you want centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
/*------------------------------------*\
    ##Loading
\*------------------------------------*/


/* Absolute Center CSS Spinner */
.u-loading {
    z-index: 9999;
}


.u-loading:not(:required):after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    content: '';
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.u-border-all {
    border: solid black 2px;
}

.address-container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}


.u-loading:not(:required)::after {
    animation: 1500ms linear 0s normal none infinite running spinner;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 1.5em 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 1.1em 1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 1.5em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), -1.1em 1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), -1.5em 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), -1.1em -1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 -1.5em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 1.1em -1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    content: "";
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;
    
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.u-loading{position:relative}
```

```html
<div class="u-loading">
<div class="address-container u-border-all">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--line u-border-bottom">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--house-no u-border-right">
    <input type="text" class="address__textbox address__textbox--street">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--line">
    <input type="text" class="address__textbox address__textbox--line">
    <input type="text" class="address__textbox address__textbox--line">
    <input type="text"  class="address__textbox address__textbox--postcode u-border-right u-border-top">
    <select class="address__textbox address__country u-border-top">
        <option value="Select a country" selected="selected" class="rps-placeholder">Select a country</option>
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
        <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NicScozzaro you can see now.

Comment: Thanks. It would also be useful to see an example of putting the spinner over one div element within the page (not covering the whole page). That's actually the google search that drew me to this page :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your spinner is in `display: inline-block`.

If you want to center it in its parent you could change its style to `display: block` along with `margin: auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.u-loading:not(:required)::after {
    animation: 1500ms linear 0s normal none infinite running spinner;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 1.5em 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 1.1em 1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 1.5em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), -1.1em 1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), -1.5em 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), -1.1em -1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 -1.5em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 1.1em -1.1em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    content: "";
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1em;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Just checked it on the jfiddle, it works but centres on the whole html page rather than the div, any suggestion ?